# Rename columns based on relatation between other columns

Tags: python, pandas

I'm struggling on finding a solution for this situation.

I have two pandas dataframes one have columns named with their ids and the other one has the correlation between the ids, real name and sector:

df1 =

| id1 | id2 | id3 | randomcol | id4 | id5 | id6 | id7 | ... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | a | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | ... |
| 7 | 6 | 5 | b | 4 | 3 | 2 | 1 | ... |
| 1 | 2 | 3 | c | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | ... |

And the correlation between ids, real names and sectors:

df2 =

| real names | id | sector |
| --- | --- | --- |
| air | 1 | 5 |
| earth | 2 | 10 |
| fire | 3 | 15 |
| water | 4 | 20 |
| wind | 5 | 25 |

I want to rename the df1 columns with their real names from df2.

I can do df1.rename(columns={"id1": "air", "id2": "earth", "id3": "fire",...}, errors="raise")

But it have around 20 different sectors so it would be a bit frustating.

Is there a better way of doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a mapping dict (Series) from `df2` and rename columns of `df1`. The trick here is to convert numeric ids (1, 2, 3, ...) to their equivalent string (id1, id2, id3, ...):

```
MAPPING = df2.assign(id='id'+df2['id'].astype(str)).set_index('id')['real names']
df1 = df1.rename(columns=MAPPING)
```

Output:

```
>>> df1
   air  earth  fire randomcol  water  wind  id6  id7
0    1      2     3         a      4     5    6    7
1    7      6     5         b      4     3    2    1
2    1      2     3         c      4     5    6    7

>>> MAPPING
id
id1      air
id2    earth
id3     fire
id4    water
id5     wind
Name: real names, dtype: object
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick and precise answer. I'm still trying to fully understand how the mapping code line means but I have already tested and it works.

Comment: The Series (`Mapping`) acts as a dict. The index (or key for a dict) is the item to replace by the value: `id1` is replaced by `air`, `id2` by `earth` and so on. Is it clear for you now?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a mapping given `df2["id"]` and `df2["real names"]` and then replace `df.columns`:

```
map = {f"id{i}": name for i, name in zip(df2["id"], df2["real names"])}
df1.columns = df1.columns.to_series().replace(map)
```

Output:

```
   air  earth  fire  randomcol  water  wind  id6  id7
0  1    2      3     a          4      5     6    7
1  7    6      5     b          4      3     2    1
2  1    2      3     c          4      5     6    7
```